# Does react-bootstrap-table-next compatible with React 18?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap-table

I have a existing react 17 application, which needs to migrate react 18. So when migrating I faced compatible issue with react-bootstrap-table-next.
"While resolving: react-bootstrap-table-next@4.0.3 Found: react@18.2.0" I dont have any option to change react-bootstrap-table-next to another table package due to this is a existing project and dont have time to re implement table feature. Appreciate any guidance or support!

I have to upgrade React 17 to 18 and when run npm install got above error.
"While resolving: react-bootstrap-table-next@4.0.3 Found: react@18.2.0"

here full error:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: react-bootstrap-table-next@4.0.3
npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^17.0.2" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react@">=16.8.0" from @emotion/react@11.8.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/@emotion/react
npm ERR!     @emotion/react@"^11.1.1" from react-select@5.2.2
npm ERR!     node_modules/react-select
npm ERR!       react-select@"^5.2.1" from the root project
npm ERR!   31 more (@fortawesome/react-fontawesome, @react-aria/ssr, ...)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^16.3.0" from react-bootstrap-table-next@4.0.3
npm ERR! node_modules/react-bootstrap-table-next
npm ERR!   react-bootstrap-table-next@"^4.0.3" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react@16.14.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   peer react@"^16.3.0" from react-bootstrap-table-next@4.0.3
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-bootstrap-table-next
npm ERR!     react-bootstrap-table-next@"^4.0.3" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

Comment: Show the full warning message.

Comment: @LinDu updated error on above summary

Comment: I think you have asked a broader level question here: [Need a help to migrate react 17 to 18](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76768115/need-a-help-to-migrate-react-17-to-18)

Comment: Yes @vighnesh153, if I skipped above issue by using "npm install react-bootstrap-table-next --save --legacy-peer-deps" will it be a issue in future?

Comment: `legacy-peer-deps` is a bit risky because it ignores the required dependencies. Libs might not be compatible in future and it could cause issues. I would recommend checking this with the library author instead, and see what is their recommendation for using with latest React.js.

Comment: Just checked their [Github issues](https://github.com/react-bootstrap-table/react-bootstrap-table2/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+react+18) and there are a lot of open issues for adding support for React 18. I think the library is unmaintained, unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks @vighnesh153, I have already raised a issue, but seems most of them are suggesting to use a alternative table for that one, but with the limited time I cant move to another table library.

Answer (score 0):

I've made an updated version that works with React 18. I added type files as well to allow use with TypeScript.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/fad-react-bootstrap-table-next

Comment: why not change it in the original repo? also Is there plans for the other packages of the bootstrap table2 like paginator or toolkit?